# wkhtmltopdf pagination issue during converting html into pdf

Tags: html, linux, ubuntu, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am converting html into pdf using wkhtmltopdf in command line and its working fine.

but only issue I am facing is related to the page size, Since my page size is A4 so it is creating the pagination in the document,

So is there any way I can create a pdf with height according to the html content height.

Since my html content page is dynamic and its height will be different every time according to the user id.

Command I am using in Linux Ubuntu environment:

```
wkhtmltopdf <source>   <destination>
```

Comment: Is there any way i can pass argument like auto height for wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 0):

OK, So i have resolved the issue , After searching lots of option and suggestion what i have used is Wkhtmltoimage and convert (ImageMagick) command .

**First i have Converted the html to image**

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage  <SOURCE HTML PATH>    <DESTINATION PATH FOR IMAGE>");
```

**Second i have converted the image to pdf**

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/convert  <SOURCE IMAGE PATH> <DESTINATION PDF PATH >");
```

which give me very long single page PDF without any pagination